# dash-ag-grid change button state in callback

Tags: python, ag-grid, plotly-dash, dash-ag-grid

Working through the examples for using dash-ag-grid.  Is there a way to change the status of the button through a callback?  I would like to be able to press a button and have it change from active to disabled, but also be able to change the status of other buttons as well.  For example, pressing one button disables that button but enables other buttons.

https://dash.plotly.com/dash-ag-grid/cell-renderer-components

```
import json
import dash_ag_grid as dag
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output, callback
import pandas as pd
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc



data = {
    "ticker": ["AAPL", "MSFT", "AMZN", "GOOGL"],
    "company": ["Apple", "Microsoft", "Amazon", "Alphabet"],
    "price": [154.99, 268.65, 100.47, 96.75],
    "buy": ["Buy" for i in range(4)],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

columnDefs = [
    {
        "headerName": "Stock Ticker",
        "field": "ticker",
    },
    {"headerName": "Company", "field": "company", "filter": True},
    {
        "headerName": "Last Close Price",
        "type": "rightAligned",
        "field": "price",
        "valueFormatter": {"function": """d3.format("($,.2f")(params.value)"""},
        "editable": True,
    },
    {
        "field": "buy",
        "cellRenderer": "DBC_Button_Simple",
        "cellRendererParams": {"color": "success"},
    },
]


defaultColDef = {
    "resizable": True,
    "sortable": True,
    "editable": False,
}


grid = dag.AgGrid(
    id="dbc-btn-simple-btn-grid",
    columnDefs=columnDefs,
    rowData=df.to_dict("records"),
    columnSize="autoSize",
    defaultColDef=defaultColDef,
    dashGridOptions={"rowHeight": 48},
)


app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SPACELAB])

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Markdown("Example of cellRenderer with custom dash-bootstrap-components Button "),
        grid,
        html.Div(id="dbc-btn-simple-value-changed"),
    ],
    style={"margin": 20},
)


@callback(
    Output("dbc-btn-simple-value-changed", "children"),
    Input("dbc-btn-simple-btn-grid", "cellRendererData"),
)
def showChange(n):
    return json.dumps(n)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)


"""
Put the following in the dashAgGridComponentFunctions.js file in the assets folder

---------------

var dagcomponentfuncs = window.dashAgGridComponentFunctions = window.dashAgGridComponentFunctions || {};

dagcomponentfuncs.DBC_Button_Simple = function (props) {
    const {setData, data} = props;

    function onClick() {
        setData();
    }
    return React.createElement(
        window.dash_bootstrap_components.Button,
        {
            onClick: onClick,
            color: props.color,
        },
        props.value
    );
};


"""
```